# set device name to a peer in session Multipeer connectivity swift3

Tags: ios, swift, mpc

I want to build an app something like queue manage that request a queue and call the queue to counter service number 1 2 3
 problem is how can I set the device to counter 1, counter 2 depends on device connected

thanks for answer

Comment: Do you want to change device name, Right?

Comment: probably yes, or set each of device to numeric because I want to show to the label that who device click the button

Comment: Are you using Multipeer Connectivity to set device name?

Comment: if it can do that. I want to show after it connected to the session

Comment: So, where do you want to show name?
In UILabel?

Comment: yes show to the uilabel something like device1 click button and show counter 1 and device 2 on counter 2

Comment: do you want the connected devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case .connected:
        print("connected", peerId)
        lbl.text = UIDevice.current.name
    case .connecting:
        print("connecting")
    case .notConnected:
        print("not Connected")
    default: break
    }
}
```

Try above code to show device name which is connected.

Comment: Can I change that to numeric ?

Comment: How you can convert device name to numeric value?

Comment: im so sorry man . I want to set the peer in session to numeric and I dont know how to write that sorry for my bad

Comment: You want to set peerID display name to your label, Right?

Comment: You cannot show in numeric but you can show peerID display name as,
lbl.text = peerId.displayName